# why PHP code inside HTML doesn't work whereas PHP works alone and HTML works alone?

Tags: php, html, parsing, nginx, nginx-config

I tried 3 things :

- a simple html file : ok
- a simple php file : ok
- a html file with some php code inside : not ok

My configuration is

- Ubuntu :

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10
Release:    21.10
Codename:   impish
```

- NGINX :

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
```

- PHP :

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ php -v
PHP 8.0.8 (cli) (built: Oct 26 2021 11:42:42) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.8, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.8, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Here is the html with the php code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
echo "My first PHP script!";
?> 
    
Hello world
    
</body>
</html>
```

i loaded the file on **firefox** browser from **local ip** (192.168.x.y) and also from **public ip** and i got the same results. i really dont know where to start, i dont find any clue on the net.

Comment: out of curiosity, what is the extension of your mixed HTML/PHP file?

Comment: The duplicate covers a lot of cases, the rest should be covered by: https://askubuntu.com/questions/134666/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-enable-php-on-nginx

Comment: What exactly is your nginx configuration?

Comment: If it's called "something.html", then no PHP code will be processed. Call it "something.php" and it will.

Comment: the html file containing php code has the `.html` extension. i rename to `.php` and load it. it works. but i dont understand why. does NGINX have anything to do with it ?

Comment: PHP is normally not executed on .html pages.
Use .htaccess to get php working while the page appears as .html in the browser address line.

Comment: i'm not using `Apache webserver` so `.htaccess` is not available. `NGINX` is the webserver. renaming `.html` to `.php` worked but it is weird for me.